# Picture or photo viewer on my Web site

Tags: asp.net, ajax, photo-gallery

Lets say I let the customer upload up to 5 pictures. I'm looking for a good way to let visitors see the images one by one.

I've seen some.. where there are thumbnails on the side/bottom (that looks like a vertical/horizontal film strip) and the default picture is the large one displayed. And viewers can click into others to show those pictures.

This could possibly be an AJAX solution. I just couldn't come up with the right keywords to Google this custom Web component. Perhaps it is "photo gallery". But I would be more interested to know what solutions developers here use for their site.

Comment: Thanks Emmett and mal-wan.
What do you guys think of this?
http://www.ajax-zoom.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps *lightbox* is the keyword you're looking for: http://www.google.com/search?q=lightbox

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this [Galleria](http://galleria.aino.se/) what you're after?

It's all implemented in Javascript so is simple to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options but on first thought, I would reach for [the fancybox jQuery plugin](http://fancybox.net/).  The third example on their home page does exactly what you described.  I've used this plugin a few times now and it's quite good.